# From single Oracle DB server license to multi-AZ RDS issue with BYOL

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I am exploring the shift of Oracle DB from on-prem to RDS in AWS. I have my own Oracle license, and I am running on a single server (no HA). I want to have Master-Slave in RDS on Multi-AZ (HA/FT). Now, I know I can bring my own license (BYOL) into RDS but what happen when I go from a sinlge license to a multi-AZ? I can't find anything online so far.

Comment: If you are talking about normal Data Guard (not Active Data Guard), then there may be no additional license required, but you will need to talk directly to Oracle Sales to confirm exactly. No one on this forum can speak for Oracle in regards to specific license requirements.

Comment: Sure that's good hint. My only initial simplified thought is that since in RDS I would have 2 DB instances (Primary and StandBy) instead of one then I would also need 2x licenses. So overall I would need to purchase one more before I can migrate..